# Can the verb "defenestrate" be applied to someone jumping out of the window?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I have only ever seen the word **defenestrate**`used in relation to the act of throwing someone else out of the window. But would this verb be appropriate when referring to someone doing it themselves?

I do not see any etymological reason not to use it in such a way, and yet I've never seen it be used in this fashion.

For instance, if I were to disembark a bus through the window, could it be said, that I "defenestrated myself"? Or does the word imply sinister\criminal nature of the act?

I've seen mentions of an extremely rare usage of the word **autodefenestration**, but I feel like it is a bit of idiosyncratic solution.

Comment: And removing a window? Acceptability is driven by use, and this word is so rare it is best avoided, never mind attempting to broaden meaning and concoct  non-word compounds.

Comment: People don't get thrown (or throw themselves) out of windows all that often. [**Defenestrate**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/defenestrate) is more usually figurative, meaning *Remove or dismiss (someone) from a position of power or authority.* If I wanted to commit defenestration on myself, the word to use is **resign**.

Comment: The word is inexorably linked to the [defenestrations of Prague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestrations_of_Prague). It isn't productive because we don't throw people out of windows to make a political statements anymore (Lecter's homage via Pazzi not withstanding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb to defenestrate is usually transitive, but it can take a reflexive pronoun as a pseudo-object:

Roadwork: A Novel By Richard Bachman, Stephen King

> Even in his dreams he thought he was awake, and in his dreams he committed suicide over and over; burned himself; bludgeoned himself by standing under an anvil and pulling a rope; ... shot himself ... defenestrated himself; ...

Return to Reichenbach By Geri Schear

> I continued rifling through the papers. A name caught my eye. “Take a look at this, Watson,” I said, handing him the document.
>
> “Carton? The fellow who defenestrated himself after changing his will
> and leaving his wife and son nothing.”